# JOIN in hive gives cartesian product

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a query in hive shown below. It gives me a cartesian product.

```
insert into table processed 
select c.plc,c.direction,c.table,t.speed as speed,t1.id
from staging t
JOIN central c 
ON (t.id = c.boxno) 
JOIN idsfortime t1 

where (   t1.epochtime >= t.time 
       OR t1.epochtime <= t.time);
```

I do not want a cartesian product . Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If the WHERE clause is stated the way you really want it, you cannot avoid a product join.  But perhaps you want to join on `t1.epochtime = t.time`.  One can't be sure without more information about the tables.

You might want to show the complete table definitions in your question.

Comment: Sure. epochtime                 string                            
       id                   string .  This is the idsfortime table. Below is the staging table :id                   string               None                
speed                string               None                
time                 string               None

Comment: What i am trying to do is finding the relevant info from central table and staging table where epochtime from idsfortable table lies between the time column in staging table. Will a UNION work here?